# Algorithm approach to merge two linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity, space-complexity

Which algorithm approach is better to merge two ascending order sorted linked lists into one ascending order sorted linked list?

**Time vs Space Complexity?**

This solution reduces space complexity of the program since a new linked list is not created and assigned unnecessarily.

> assume head1 and head2 the head nodes of lists

```
if(head1==null && head2==null)  return null;
if(head1==null && head2!=null)  return head2;
if(head1!=null && head2==null)  return head1;

    //assigning mergeLists head to min of both head
    SinglyLinkedListNode t1, t2, c;
    if(head1.data<head2.data){
            t1 = head1;
            t2 = head2;
            c = head1;
    }else{
            t1 = head2;
            t2 = head1;
            c = head2;
    }

    //sorting both lists within without creating new list
    while(t1.next!=null){
            if(t1.next.data <= t2.data) t1 = t1.next;
            else{
            SinglyLinkedListNode temp = t1.next;
            t1.next = t2;
            t1 = t1.next;
            t2 = temp;
            }
    }
    t1.next = t2;
    return c;
```

This one is classic recursive approach better in terms of time complexity.

> assume a as head1 and b as head2

```
MergeSorted(Node a, Node b)
    if (a == null && b == null)
                return null;
            if a==null
                return b;
            if b==null
                return a;

            Node c //Combined List // new list
            if((a).data<(b).data)
                c=a;
                (c).next=MergeSorted((a).next,b);
            else
                c=b;
                (c).next=MergeSorted(a,(b).next);      
            return c;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these creates a new list.  `c` is merely another reference to a list node, not a new object.

Your first statement, checking both lists for `null`, adds nothing to the program: the immediately following `if` will do the same job on its own.

Neither of these is superior in time *complexity*; they're each **O(a+b)** on the two list lengths.  The differences are in clarity and maintainability.  Since you haven't defined your metric for "better" in any other terms, the question is moot.

Comment: this another reference c, will take up memory as the nodes are getting created, the memory will get doubled at the end, so is this approach be taken in terms of memory allocation?

Comment: `c` is yet another reference variable, not a series of new nodes.

Comment: can you please elaborate the 2nd algorithm how c is getting referenced?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that phrase.  all three variables (`a b c`) are pointers / references to list nodes.  There is no creation of a new node in any of this.  `c` walks through the new, combined list.